# How to get the sum of output set of values in python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 5, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 1, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 3, 'l': 2, 'm': 3, 'n': 4, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 6, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 7, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 5, 'y': 4, 'z': 4
}
```

When a word is given, I have to calculate the total value of that word.

For example, if the word is apple, `value = (value for a) + (value for p) + (value for p) + (value for l) + (value for e) = 1 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10.`

So far I have done the following:

```
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    Dictionary.get(word[i])
```

This gives me the following output:

```
1
3
3
2
1
```

So my question is how to add these values (the outputs of each word) and produce the sum of these (in this example 10, as calculated above) ?

Comment: Please fix the syntax. This helps to make your question more readable.

Comment: `sum(map(Dictionary.get, word))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum will take an iterable:

```
sum(Dictionary[c] for c in 'apple')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = 0
for x in word:
    result += Dictionary[x]
print(result)
```

However, `Dictionary` is a reserved word, so you should use some other variable name.

Comment: `Dictionary` is *not* a "reserved word" (the built-in type is `dict`, which is also not reserved, although shouldn't be used to avoid shadowing).

Comment: Why it is highlighted in blue?

Comment: On SO? Because it starts with a capital, and is therefore formatted as a `ClassName`.

Comment: No problem. There are few truly reserved words in Python usually called "keywords" - see e.g. http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/keywords-in-python